# How to check if selected timeframe period is lower than a given period?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Suppose, currently selected `timeframe.period` is '**D**' *(1 day)*. How do we check if it is lower than '**W**' *(1 week)* ?

```
ta.lowest('D', 'W') ??
```

I can't seem to find any built-in functions for that. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found an example here: https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/

Basically, you convert the current timeframe and the timeframe you want it to compare to minutes and then you compare those minutes

```
// ————— Converts timeframe into a float minutes value.
f_tfInMinutes(_TF) => 
    _tfInMinutes = timeframe.multiplier * (
      _TF == "1S" or _TF == "15S" or _TF == "30S" ? 1. / 60             :
      _TF == "1m" or _TF == "2m" or _TF == "5m" .... ? 1.                  :
      _TF == "D"   ? 60. * 24            :
      _TF == "W"  ? 60. * 24 * 7        :
      _TF == "M" ? 60. * 24 * 30.4375  : na)
```

Comment: It's better to use the built-in `timeframe.in_seconds()` function for this, it should be faster computation-wise.

Comment: @beeholder not to mention it handles custom time frames as well.